# Problem with function that provides a range of numbers (C). Why?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have created a function that provides a range of numbers based off of one number, and the amount of numbers you want to get that are away from the number (I know, that explanation was kind of vague, so here is an example):

```
Number of origin: 10
Number of numbers to count away from the origin: 5
Output:
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

So here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void plusMinus(int*change, int num, int funcTo){

    int range = funcTo * 2;
    int start = num - funcTo;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<=range; i++){
        change[i] = start + i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int* pointer;
    plusMinus(&pointer, 250, 5);
    int x;
    for (x=0; x<=10; x++){
        printf("%d\n", &pointer[x]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the **desired** output:

```
245
246
247
248
249
250
251
252
253
254
255
```

and here is the current output:

```
245
249
253
257
261
265
269
273
277
281
285
```

The code is also returning two warnings, but I have no idea as to what they mean. Here is the first one:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'plusMinus' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

and here is the second:

```
warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
```

Comment: `plusMinus` expects an `int *` as its first argument.  You are passing an `int **`. Turn up the compiler warnings.

Comment: You never allocated space for `pointer` to point to.

Comment: @WilliamPursell He did get a warning.

Comment: The address-of operator results in a pointer to what you use it on. If you use it on a pointer variable, you get a pointer to the pointer variable, i.e. a pointer to a pointer. For your variable `pointer`, the type of `&pointer` is `int **`.

Comment: The argument corresponding to `%d` in `printf()` should be `int`. But you're using `&pointer[i]`, which is `int*`, not `int`. There's no need to use `&` with `printf()`, that's only done with `scanf()`.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed.  @Serket, the first warning is because you are passing `int **` rather than `int *`.

Comment: When using a `for` loop to iterate over an array, the repeat test should almost always use `<` rather than `<=`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I fixed all the bugs and it works well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first function parameter has the type `int *`

```
void plusMinus(int*change, int num, int funcTo){
```

but you are passing an argument of the type `int **`

```
int* pointer;
plusMinus(&pointer, 250, 5);
```

Moreover the pointer `pointer` is uninitialized and has indeterminate value. As a result the program has undefined behavior.

In this call of `printf`

```
printf("%d\n", &pointer[x]);
```

the conversion specifier `%d` expects an object of the type `int` while you are passing an object of the type `int *`.

Here is your updated program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void plusMinus( int *a, int num, int funcTo )
{
    int range = 2 * funcTo + 1;
    int start = num - funcTo;

    for ( int i = 0; i <range; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = start + i;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int funcTo = 5;
    int a[2 * funcTo + 1];

    plusMinus( a, 250, funcTo );

    for ( int i = 0; i  < 2 * funcTo + 1; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ",  a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255
```

It is more interesting to write the function as a recursive function.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void plusMinus( int *a, int num, int funcTo )
{
    a[0] = num - funcTo;

    if ( funcTo ) 
    {
        plusMinus( a + 1, num, funcTo - 1 );

        a[2 * funcTo] = num + funcTo;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int funcTo = 5;
    int a[2 * funcTo + 1];

    plusMinus( a, 250, funcTo );

    for ( int i = 0; i  < 2 * funcTo + 1; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ",  a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

```
245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255
```